# Wrap a function around an other one in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following code:

```
self.csn(0)
self.spidev.xfer2(txbuffer)
self.csn(1)
```

which sets the csn-Pin first low then runs the spi stuff and then sets the csn-Pin high again. This approach works but it looks not very "pythonic". Is there a method to "inject" the function that it would look like something like this

```
wrapping_function()
    function_todo
```

This is pure cosmetic but i think there is a way i just cant find it

Comment: Check out decorators, I think that might be what you're going for

Comment: I found decorators but i cant find a way with them to call the second part (self.csn(1)) with a decorator. As i understood them they wil call a function in the end but maybe i just didnt understand them right

Comment: problem with this is that i have to wrap a bunch of functions with this method not only this one. so i can write a new function everytime but then it feels "unpythonic" again

Comment: There is very little explanation of the problem here and it is at all not clear what the OP is trying to do with the wrapping function

Comment: there's nothing unpythonic about wrapping several lines of code in a function call, especially if it's code that you're going to be re-using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for higher order functions: a function that takes another function as a parameter:

```
def run(f):
  self.csn(0)
  f()
  self.csn(1)
```

Then, for your example use:

```
run(lambda: self.spidev.xfer2(txbuffer))
```

We're passing a function in the form of a `lambda`. `run` then runs that passed function between the two calls to `csn`.

Comment: I think thats what i looked for :) the lambda call is brilliant thank you very much

Comment: @MichaelKirsch No problem. In retrospect, sardok's context manager example may actually be more pythonic, even if it is slightly more complex. I forgot Python had that honestly.

Comment: yes his approach looks very good too. both are more readable than my first piece of code

Comment: In the end i ended up with this: def stuff():
    print("2")
    return "end"

def csn_call(func):
    print("1")
    d = func()
    print("3")
    return d

v= csn_call(lambda: stuff())

print (v)

Answer (score 3):

You may use `contextmanager`.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def csn_context(csn_obj):
    try:
        csn_obj.csn(0)
        yield
    finally:
        csn_obj.csn(1)

with csn_context(self):
    self.spidev.xfer2(txbuffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `decorator` for this:

```
def wrapping_function(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        self.csn(0)
        f = func(*args, **kwargs)
        self.csn(1)
        return f

    return wrapper

@wrapping_function
def xfer2(txbuffer):
    do_something
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Wrap a function in another function", I hear decorator. Take a look at the following code:

```
import functools
def decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        self.csn(0)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        self.csn(1)
    return wrap
```

Put this decorator over the `self.spidev.xfer2(txbuffer)` function with the syntax `@decorator` in the same way `@functools` is used above. Anytime you want to wrap a function in this manner you simply need to put the decorator over the function declaration.